# given java class name and a pair of jar files, find the parent classname in each jarfile

Tags: java, jar

I'm writing a tool which is supposed to determine what classes have changed when a system is upgraded. What i have as input are:
1 - the jar file used with the pre-upgraded system
2 - the jar file used with the post-upgraded system
3 - a list of classes and their purpose that I care about
      asset init package1.myasset.class
      asset terminate package1.assetterminate.class
      etc.

What I want to do is be able to load the jar that comes with the new system and the jar that came with the old system and determine if a given class has the same parent after the change that it did before the change. i.e. if in the new system asset init
1 - is still package1.myasset.class and
2 - is still an extension of package0.generalasset.class

I assume I can use reflection but I'm not sure how to determine what a given classes parent is in each jar to see if it changed.

The jars are not necessarily used directly (runtime) by my tool - in fact they shouldn't really be used except as an input to the analysis of the system change.

Comment: if I was in your shoes, since you don't actually have to use these jars, I'd extract the classes (or list the jar contents), sort and diff both using unix tools.

Comment: but, if you still want to use reflection, I suggest you to take a look at http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need two `URLClassLoaders,` one for each JAR file.
2. Process your list of classes and load each one in turn via both classloaders.
3. Do not attempt to cast them, they are just `Class<?>` at this stage.
4. Call `Class.getSuperClass()` on each, and then `getName()` on each parent class.
5. Compare.

Comment: Hi and thank you. I ended up using a snippet I found on this site which adds the jar file(s) to the system class loader. This is very close to what I ended up finding useful... it was the "flawlessly" answer here to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/60766/339274

Answer (score 0):

Although there are many possibly important changes to a class other than its (single) parent, if that's really all you need I wouldn't bother with code, I'd just put both jars on a system with JDK and do:

```
javap -classpath jar1 aclassname |grep extends 
javap -classpath jar2 aclassname |grep extends
# or substitute findstr on unimproved Windows 
# repeat for multiple classes as desired
```

If you want to look for any change in the "public API", the full `javap` output is a good start.